# Understanding the definition of the Group action.

Tags: group-theory, intuition, group-actions, motivation

Quoting from [Wolfram definition of group action](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Group.html)  -

In general, a group action is when a group acts on a set, permuting its elements, so that the map from the group to the permutation group of the set is a homomorphism.

Is it always that when a group acts on a set it will always permute its elements? Like permutation word comes up then I can think of permutation group $S_{n}$, but like what happens when some other group acts on the set?

Also, a map from the group to the permutation group of the set is a homomorphism is like saying that there is a homomorphism between the group and the set of elements, hmm is it intuitive?

Also are there any stunning group action applications or visualizations?

Comment: I know there are other equivalent definitions, but I prefer to define a group action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ as a homomorphism $\phi:G \to {\rm Sym}(X)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a group $G$ acts on any set $X$, the reason that the action of a group element $g \in G$ is a permutation --- i.e. a bijection --- is because it has an inverse, namely the action of $g^{-1}$. By definition of group action, the action of $g \in G$ followed by the action of $h \in G$ is equal to the action of $hg$; that's why we say the action is a homomorphism.

As a consequence, the action of $g$ on $X$, composed with the action of $g^{-1}$ on $X$ is equal to the action of $g^{-1} g = \text{Id}$ on $X$, which is the identity map. Similarly the action of $g^{-1}$ composed with the action of $g$ is equal to the action of $g g^{-1} = \text{Id}$. It follows that the action of $g$ is a permutation.

As for "stunning" examples, any time you have a highly symmetric object, i.e. the 2-sphere $S^2 = \{(x,y,z) \mid x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\}$, the symmetries of $S^2$ form an interesting and often useful group. In this case, the symmetries of $S^2$ are the orthogonal group $O(3)$, the group of $3 \times 3$ matrices $M$ such that $M M^T = M^T M = \text{Id}_{3 \times 3}$. The usual vector multiplication formula $Mv$, restricted to unit vectors $v=\langle x,y,z\rangle$, defines the action of $O(3)$ on $S^2$. There are many, many other interesting actions like this in geometry.

Answer (score 1):

There's always a trivial action from any group to any set, which doesn't transitively permute everything. In general, we can think of a group action of $G$ on a set $X$ as a map $\phi:G\to S_X$, the symmetric group on elements of $X$. The group action, therefore, contains all the permutations of $X$ when the map $\phi$ is surjective. We don't want to say that this group action is a homomorphism between $G$ and $X$, because $X$ doesn't have any native structure. It's $S_X$, the permutation group, that has the structure that we want to deal with, and we already have a word for group homomorphisms.

In general, group actions are the way we study finite groups. A group acting on itself by conjugation gives us the class equation, which says that $|G|=|Z(G)|+\sum|\kappa_x|$, where $\kappa_x=\{y\in G\,|\,\exists g\in G \text{ s.t. } gxg^{-1}=y\}$. This approach also gives us the Sylow theorems, which are a sort of partial converse to Cauchy's theorem: for each prime $p$ with $p^k\big||G|$, there is a subgroup of $G$ of size $p^k$. In fact, one of the proofs for Cauchy's theorem also uses group actions and the orbit-stabilizer theorem.

Answer (score 1):

"Permutation" is not a good word unless you are specifically focused on actions on finite sets. A group action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ is equivalent to a group homomorphism $G\to\mathsf{Bij}(X)$, where $\mathsf{Bij}(X)$ is the group of bijections, i.e. invertible functions, on $X$. When $X$ is a finite set, then this will be the group of permutations of the elements of $X$. The homomorphism $G\to\mathsf{Bij}(X)$ is not like a homomorphism from $G$ to $X$ as that doesn't even make sense: no group structure is defined or required for $X$. The homomorphism maps $g\in G$ to an invertible *function* $X\to X$ where the group structure is defined by function composition.

Historically, mathematicians usually cared about group actions. It was only later that the idea of a group became a stand-alone concept. [Noether's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) completely revolutionized how we conceptualize physics and it is about (Lie) group actions. It produces results like the conservation of energy is due to symmetry under time translation. The [Standard Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) is a [gauge theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_gauge_theory) and the [gauge symmetries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_symmetry) referred to are with respect to (Lie) group actions. This is closely related to Noether's theorem.

Comment: @MorganRodgers If $X$ is something other than a plain set, then this gives a coherent notion of "group action" just in an enriched context. But that is a bit of an advanced point, so I'll reword it a bit. I still dislike "permutation" for bijections on infinite and especially uncountably infinite sets.